# changing tab color based on tab name excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to change tab colors based on the name of the tab cell. I tried to have my version choose from a list of names to change the tab name:

```
Sub SheetTabColor()

        Dim mySheets As Worksheets
        Dim mySheet As Worksheet

        Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("Christine", "Marina", "Roberto", "Urszula", "Lois", "Matt", "Stephanie", "Sally", "Iryna", "Katherine", "Matthew", "Julio", "Lavinia"))

        For Each mySheet In mySheets
            mySheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
        Next


    End Sub
```

After running this script I get an error at the "Set mySheets=" line

[image: Error Msg]

Any feedback would be appreciated, I understand that i might not even be close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it puts the name array as strings instead of sheets.

```
Sub SheetTabColor()

    Dim mySheets() As Variant
    Dim mySheet As Variant

    mySheets = Array("Christine", "Marina", "Roberto", "Urszula", "Lois", "Matt", "Stephanie", "Sally", "Iryna", "Katherine", "Matthew", "Julio", "Lavinia")

    For Each mySheet In mySheets
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheet).Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    Next

End Sub
```

This code will fail if any of the names in the array are not found as a worksheet name.

The following will skip any not found:

```
Sub SheetTabColor()

    Dim mySheets() As Variant
    Dim mySheet As Variant

    mySheets = Array("Christine", "Marina", "Roberto", "Urszula", "Lois", "Matt", "Stephanie", "Sally", "Iryna", "Katherine", "Matthew", "Julio", "Lavinia")

    For Each mySheet In mySheets
        On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheet).Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the preferred approach, though for context if it was still desirable to array the sheets you could also do `mySheets = Array(sheets("Christine"),sheets("Marina"))` etc.

Comment: FWIW this code is **much** more robust and consistent than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Zerk except using `Sheets("abc")` destroys the strength of this answer, which is explicitly qualifying the collection with a proper `Workbook` object, and uses the `Worksheets` collection to dereference the `Worksheet` objects, as opposed to the `Sheets` collection, which can yield surprises. My only problem with this approach is the `For Each` loop being used to iterate an array, but with that few items involved it shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Mat'sMug just curious and always eager to learn, how would you do it without the loop?

Comment: Oh there *would* be a loop - either a `For Each` loop to iterate an object collection, or a `For` loop to iterate an array =)

Comment: so is a regular `For` loop quicker and/or better than a `For Each` loop? @Mat'sMug

Comment: [Depends what's being iterated](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you, leant myself somtin' new today.

Answer (score 4):

> Sheets is not same as Worksheets.
>
> ---

You are trying to assign `Sheets` to `Worksheets`, hence the error.

Use same type and the code works.

```
Sub test()

    Dim mySheets As Sheets
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet

    Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
    For Each mySheet In mySheets
        mySheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
    Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: If the code means to be working exclusively with `Worksheet`-sheets, then instead of `[ActiveWorkbook.]Sheets` it should be `[ActiveWorkbook.]Worksheets`. A `Sheets` collection can hold any type of sheet, *including* `Worksheet`, but also e.g. `Chart` sheets. That said the whole wrapping-the-array-with-a-sheet-collection thing is over-the-top IMO.